# partial panel background color in IE8 when frame is enabled

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-8, frame

I have an extJS panel in which I would like to have a grey background, and grey frame.  I have the following settings:

```
    var defaults = {
    layout: 'hbox',
    border: false,
    frame:true,
    style: {background:'#333333 !important'},
    bodyStyle: {background: '#333333', border: 'none'},
    items: [
        baseFilters,
        advFilters
    ]}
```

When I render this in chrome it works fine.  The background is grey, and the frame is present, and the frame background is grey.  However, when it is enabled in IE8, the background beneath the items is grey, and the frame background is grey, but the area that is in the panel but not underneath the items is the origional blue.  There is also a blue outline around the entire panel within the frame that is blue (probably about 7px wide).

Has anyone had these issues before that can offer some insight on how to remove the blue?

PS.

This renders fine in chrome and firefox with these settings